# App engine returning 400 error for access token request

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, oauth-provider

I was trying to implement oauth javascript client using Google app engine oauth end points.
I registered my myapp.appspot.com domain with my google account.
I was able to retrieve the verification.
But received a 400 error trying to fetch the access token.
Did anyone successfully receive an access token from Google app engine end points?
If so please help me.
Using the following code.

```
    function getRequestToken() {
    token = {};
    oauthRequest("https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken" , { oauth_callback: "https://myapp.appspot.com/index"}, gotRequestToken);
  }
    function gotRequestToken() {
    parseToken(req.responseText);
    authorize();
    }
    function authorize() {
        deleteTab = false;
    chrome.tabs.create({
        "url":"https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=" +     token.oauth_token,
        "selected":true
    }, function(theTab) {
        if(deleteTab){
        chrome.tabs.remove(theTab.id);
      } else {
        deleteTab = theTab;
      }
    });
```

when i granted access to myapp.appspot.com, i get a oauth_verifier in the url, which i successfully captured and passed to the following request.

```
oauthRequest("https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken", {  "oauth_verifier":     data.verifier }, gotAccessToken);
function gotAccessToken() {
alert ('got access token');
parseToken(req.responseText);
storeToken();
}
```

But it is this final access token request that fails! giving 400 error.
And am using [oauthsimple javascript library](http://unitedheroes.net/OAuthSimple/js/OAuthSimple.js).